# TLS error when connecting to local MQTT broker from iOS client

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm getting the following error when connecting to my local mosquitto MQTT broker with TLS (self signed certificate) from my iOS client:

> SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number.

`mosquitto.conf`

```
...
listener 8883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
require_certificate true
cafile /opt/homebrew/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /opt/homebrew/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /opt/homebrew/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
...
```

Certificate creation:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key ca.key -out ca.crt (CN=CA)
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -out server.csr -key server.key (CN=localhost)
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -out client.csr -key client.key (CN=localhost)
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.p12 -inkey client.key -in client.crt -certfile ca.crt
openssl x509 -inform pem -in ca.crt -outform der -out root.der
```

iOS client certificate parsing (client.p12, root.der):

```swift
public static func importIdentities(from url: URL, password: String) throws -> [SecIdentity] {
    let p12Data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let options: [String: String] = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as String: password]

    var rawItems: CFArray?
    let result = DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        SecPKCS12Import(p12Data as CFData, options as CFDictionary, &rawItems)
    }

    guard result == errSecSuccess else {
        if result == errSecAuthFailed {
            throw Error.invalidPassword
        } else {
            throw Error.invalidData
        }
    }

    guard let items = rawItems as? [[CFString: SecIdentity]] else {
        throw Error.invalidData
    }

    return items.compactMap({ $0[kSecImportItemIdentity] })
}

public static func importCertificate(from url: URL) throws -> SecCertificate {
    let certificateData = try Data(contentsOf: url) as CFData
    guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData) else {
        throw Error.invalidData
    }
    return certificate
}
```

iOS client `NWProtocolTLS.Options`:

```swift
func getNWProtocolTLSOptions() -> NWProtocolTLS.Options {
    let options = NWProtocolTLS.Options()

    sec_protocol_options_set_min_tls_protocol_version(options.securityProtocolOptions, minimumTLSVersion)

    if let maximumTLSVersion = maximumTLSVersion {
        sec_protocol_options_set_max_tls_protocol_version(options.securityProtocolOptions, maximumTLSVersion)
    }

    if let clientIdentity = clientIdentity, let secClientIdentity = sec_identity_create(clientIdentity) {
        sec_protocol_options_set_local_identity(options.securityProtocolOptions, secClientIdentity)
    }

    securityProtocols.forEach {
        sec_protocol_options_add_tls_application_protocol(options.securityProtocolOptions, $0)
    }

    if trustRootCertificates != nil {
        sec_protocol_options_set_verify_block(options.securityProtocolOptions, { _, sec_trust, sec_protocol_verify_complete in
            let trust = sec_trust_copy_ref(sec_trust).takeRetainedValue()

            if let trustRootCertificates = trustRootCertificates {
                SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, trustRootCertificates as CFArray)
            }

            SecTrustEvaluateAsyncWithError(trust, queue) { _, result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    log.error("Trust failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                sec_protocol_verify_complete(result)
            }
        }, queue)
    }

    return options
}
```

I can establish the connection but get the following error in the client logs:

> [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1.1.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]

And the broker logs are as follows:

```
1671167575: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1671167575: Config loaded from /opt/homebrew/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1671167575: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1671167575: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1671167575: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
1671167582: New connection from 127.0.0.1:56685 on port 8883.
1671167582: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
1671167582: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

Anyone know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Do you have any `NWConnection` code?

Comment: What values do you have set for `minimumTLSVersion` and `maximumTLSVersion`?